# why does this keep printing "out of range try again"? and how can i fix it

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

For some reason this will print out "out of range please try again". I tried changing the if statements but that doesn't work either.

```
#define MAX_fn_LEN32
#define MAX_ln_LEN32
#define MAX_stA_LEN64
#define MAX_city_LEN32
#define MAX_state_LEN32
#define MAX_buffer_LEN32
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(){

char* fn=NULL;
bool a=false;

fn = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));;

printf("what is your first name?\n");
scanf("%s",fn);

while(a==false){

  if(fn==NULL ||fn>=(32*sizeof(char))){

    printf("Out of range try again.\n");
    scanf("%s",fn);
    a=false;
  }
  else{

    printf("This works.\n");
    a = true;
    return 0;
}

}
  free(fn);

}
```

For some reason this will print out "out of range please try again". I tried changing the if statements but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you expect the `fn>=(32*sizeof(char))` comparison to do? You are comparing an address with the number `32`.

Comment: `fn` is a pointer. Comparing it against a size like `fn>=(32*sizeof(char))` is incorrect.

Comment: Also I do not understand this manipulation with `a`. It only becomes `true` right before the program termination.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? It's weird enough so we are unable to guess. [Edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: `if(fn==NULL ||fn>=(32*sizeof(char))){` is essentially a pass-through.  Whether `malloc` is successful or not (as long as the address is greater than 32) it will call your printf resulting in `out of range please try again`  BTW `sizeof(char)` is `1` always.  so `32 * sizeof(char)` is just `32`.

Comment: The only thing to check from the return value of `malloc` is `NULL` or not `NULL`. If it returns not `NULL`, then it successfully gave you the amount of memory you asked for, there's no need (and no way) to check that `malloc` gave you the correct number of bytes. It's all or nothing. You need to maintain how much memory you've requested yourself.

Comment: `fn` will be the return of `malloc`, which is probably greater or equal 32.

Comment: Trying to read a first-name with maximum length 31? reject & retry if it exceeds that length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(fn==NULL ||fn>=(32*sizeof(char))){
```

does not make a sense.

There is compared an address stored in the pointer `fn` with the value `32 * ( sizeof( char )`.

It seems you mean

```
if(fn==NULL || strlen( fn ) >=(32*sizeof(char))){
```

But if the condition indeed evaluates to true then your program has undefined behavior.
To check whether `fn` is equal to NULL you should do after the memory allocation as for example

```
fn = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));;
if ( fn != NULL )
{
    printf("what is your first name?\n");
    if ( scanf("%31s",fn) == 1 )
    {
        printf("This works.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ryyker It is evident because he is doing that after reading  a string.

Comment: Good point -- you need to limit the input to the size of the array before, not check if the limit was reached _a posteriori_. Calling `scanf` in this way suffers the same buffer overflow weakness as `gets`.